# Why does this iPhone app crash?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

The console only says this, and the app won't get past Default.PNG without crashing

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Simple_RSSAppDelegate 0x5248d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key viewController.'
```

2009-08-08 22:23:54.135 Simple RSS[13199:20b] Stack: (
    2514415595,
    2485665339,
    2514414353,
    2453313768,
    2453312334,
    2453856193,
    818019035,
    2514369317,
    818013737,
    818022028,
    816113908,
    816149067,
    2453391502,
    2513918197,
    2513918632,
    827745792,
    827745989,
    816114848,
    816160924,
    11212,
    11066
)

***PLEASE HELP ME OUT !!!!!!!!!***

Comment: an example of the code involved would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without more info, the error sounded vaguely familiar. [This write-up may help you out in getting this resolved.](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/07/iphone-workshop-frequently-ask.html)

Answer (score 1):

There's no `viewController` property in your app delegate but you still use it from a nib file.